# Does not contain constructor that take 1 argument "4"

Tags: c#

I have found that so many people asking about this error but I could find a proper answer with explanation about that.

Class:`Update`

```
 public class Log
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string fullname { set; get; }

    public Log() {

    }
    public Log(LogDs.LogFileRow row)
    {
        this.id = row.id;
        this.type = row.type;
        this.action = row.action.ToString();
        this.description = row.description.ToString();
        this.date = row.date;
        this.fullname = row.fullname;
    }
}
```

Bc class:

```
public class LogBC
{
    LogDalc dalc = new LogDalc();

    public List<Log> List(DateTime dateStart, DateTime dateEnd)
    {
        List<Log> listLog = new List<Log>();

        LogDs.LogFileDataTable dt = dalc.Sel(dateStart, dateEnd);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Count; i++)
        {
            Log exp = new Log(dt[i]);

            listLog.Add(exp);
        }

        return listLog;
    }
```

Dalc Class:

```
public class LogDalc: BaseDalc
{

    public LogDs.LogFileDataTable Sel(DateTime dateStart, DateTime dateEnd)
    {
        LogDs ds = new LogDs();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Global.Config.ConnStr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spp_txn_expenses_sel", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sdate", dateStart == DateTime.MinValue ? dbNull : dateStart));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@edate", dateEnd == DateTime.MinValue ? dbNull : dateEnd));

            FillDataSet(cmd, ds, new string[] { ds.LogFile.TableName });
        }

        return ds.LogFile;
    }

}
```

error is shown in Bc class and exactly in `Log exp = new Log(dt[i]);`. Could anyone explain why this happened and how to solve it?

Comment: Does not contain constructor that take 1 argument.

Comment: I have updated my code with constructor but still shows the same error

Comment: What is the type of dt[i] member ? LogFileRow?

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor on `Log` class that accepts a single parameter.

Provide the parameterized constructor:

```
public class Log
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string fullname { set; get; }

    public Log(object myValue) {
      // your logic for myValue assignment to some property
    }
}
```

Or use inline assignment of properties

```
Log exp = new Log() { Description = dt[i].ToString() };
```

Comment: Make your constructor parameter of type object and see if it produces the error!. I have updated the code in answer as follows

Comment: it must use DataSet for some proposes, as you can see `LogDs` is dataset

Answer (score 0):

Your `Log` class doesn't know what to do with the parameter you're passing it. You need to define a constructor that takes that kind of parameter:

```
public Log(LogDs.LogFileDataTable dt)
{
    // initialize your settings from the DataTable here
}
```